# Modification of storage_content.txt file in SimGrid

Tags: c, simgrid

The storage_content.txt is applied for description of storage content of the host.
For example the excerpt of it:

```
/doc/simgrid/examples/platforms/g5k.xml  17028
```

But when I change the size of g5k.xml to **another** value:

```
/doc/simgrid/examples/platforms/g5k.xml  56245
```

The `descriptor function` of SimGrid always gives the **old** value:

```
Full path: '/home/doc/simgrid/examples/platforms/g5k.xml'
Size: 17028
Mount point: '/home'
Storage Id: 'Disk4'
Storage Type: 'single_SSD'
Content Type: 'txt_unix'
File Descriptor Id: 0
```

Or:
When I "add" the new file to `storage_content.xml` with some byte size the descriptor mistakenly gives:

```
Full path: '/home/new_folder/new_file.xml'
Size: 0
Mount point: '/home'
Storage Id: 'Disk4'
Storage Type: 'single_SSD'
Content Type: 'txt_unix'
File Descriptor Id: 0
```

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way (so far) to make the content of this file permanent from one simulation to another. The content is not saved to disk when the simulation ends, so it is reset to its original content when the simulator starts.

In addition, there is no link between the actual content of the SimGrid archive and the content of this file. It was generated from the listing of our archive at some point, but this is in no way synchronized with the filesystem. If you want to read something in this file, just edit the file that is never modified automatically during the build or whatsoever.